# Adding PlotLabel in individual plot creates white box when "showing" two plots

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am creating a line plot (pl1) with a specifically placed PlotLabel and then I show both pl1 and pl2 (pl2 is a contour plot). The PlotLabel from pl1 appears with a white highlighted box behind it. How do I remove this?

This is my code and a

```
pl1 = Plot[(10^15)/x, {x, 10^(-7), 10^(-3)}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"},
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, White}, 
  PlotLabels -> Placed["Curve", {2*10^-5, 0.4*10^21}], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[White]];
pl2 = ContourPlot[
  1/(a^(2/3)*b^2), {a, 10^(-3), 10^(-7)}, {b, 10^8, 10^23}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10", "Log10"}];
Show[pl2, pl1]
```

And here is the plot

[image]

Comment: this seems to be version related issue. The issue does not arise in version 11.3 (windows 10-64). I get the picture as yours in version 12.0 (wolfram cloud).